# Is it a good idea to nest custom serializer classes in django?

Tags: django

So I have this code and it is working:

```
class X(serializers.Serializer):
    class Y(serializers.Serializer):
        class Z(serializers.Serializer):
            id = serializers.IntegerField()
            description = serializers.CharField()

        stdout = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
        time = serializers.FloatField()
        memory = serializers.FloatField()
        stderr = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
        token = serializers.CharField()
        compile_output = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
        message = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
        status = Z()

    submissions = Y(many=True)
```

But is this a good idea to nest serializer classes? The nested classes(Y and Z) are only used within X class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is workable, but there is a better format. Instead of throwing everything in one class, it is better to have them declared as separate classes and then include it in your serializer.

[Referenced from docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example).